# Guardar Coordenadas Google Sheets

Tags: qr

Buen dia a todos, el problema es el siguiente:

Tengo una hoja de google sheets en la que se guardan como control de asistencia datos basicos, se genera un qr y al escanearlo los datos parametrizados en ese qr se guardan en la hoja de calculo, el problema es que adicional a eso quiero guardar las coordenadas actuales, ya he buscado mil formas pero no doy con la solucion, el codigo es el siguiente:

```
function doGet(e) {
   // Cambia aquí tu idioma-país y zona horaria
  //const fecha = new Date().toLocaleString("es-MX", {timeZone:"America/Caracas"});

  //Obtenemos el correo de la cuenta ejecutando el registro
  const correo = Session.getActiveUser() .getEmail();

  // Registramos la asistencia usando el correo y los parámetros que vienen en la URL
  registrarAsistencia(correo, e.parameter.id, e.parameter.jerarquia, e.parameter.nombre, e.parameter.apellido);

  // Damos retroalimentación sobre lo que sucedió:
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(`
   DATOS DEL REGISTRO. <br><br>
   Correo que Registró: ${correo}<br>
   Fecha: ${new Date()}<br>
   ID: ${e.parameter.id}<br>
   Jerarquia: ${e.parameter.jerarquia}<br>
   Nombre: ${e.parameter.nombre}<br>
   Apellido: ${e.parameter.apellido} `);
}

function registrarAsistencia(correo, id, jerarquia, nombre,apellido,Location) {
  // Debes cambiar este identificador por el de tu documento de hoja de cálculo
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("aca pongo la direccion de la hoja de calculo");
  const asistencia = sheet.getSheetByName("Asistencia");
  const lastRow = asistencia.getLastRow() + 1;
  asistencia.getRange(lastRow, 1).setValue(correo);
  asistencia.getRange(lastRow, 2).setValue(id);
  asistencia.getRange(lastRow, 3).setValue(jerarquia);
  asistencia.getRange(lastRow, 4).setValue(nombre);
  asistencia.getRange(lastRow, 5).setValue(apellido);
  asistencia.getRange(lastRow, 6).setValue(new Date());
  
}
```